# Redirect to different domain in using IIS URL Redirect Module not redirecting

Tags: iis, redirect

I'm using IIS 8.5 with the URL Redirect module installed.

My use case is that we have a defunct web site (www.xyz.com) and would like all requests to this site be redirected to another site (www.123.com).  In the web.config of www.xyz.com I've added the following code:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <globalRules>
      <rule name="Redirect to 123.com" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.123.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </globalRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I don't get any errors but I don't get a redirect either.  It just goes to www.xyz.com as always.  What am I missing to get this redirect to work?

Thanks

Comment: xyz.com and 123.com are on the same webserver ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is, does DNS for www.xyz.com point to the same IP address as www.123.com? Sorry for asking here in an "Answer", but I don't have enough points to add a comment yet.

Second, assuming number one is correct, your rewrite rule has no conditions specified so it would do this redirect for every request to your site, even if the URL already specified www.123.com. Try this instead:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to 123.com" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.xyz\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.123.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think changing the DNS makes sense.  I can't point the DNS (for xyz.com) at 123.com because it's a hosted site and I'm only allowed one domain.  The idea is that whatever requests come to xyz.com, they're redirected to 123.com.  I tried your updated RegEx in the condition node but it still resolves to xyz.com.

Comment: @BKahuna so are you adding this rule to the webserver that hosts xyz.com?

Comment: Yes, I'm modifying the web.config on xyz.com.  123.com is hosted site with a shared IP.

Comment: @BKahuna You need to install the latest Application Request Routing on xyz server. Do you have access to IIS manager on it? Navigate to the site, then click URL Rewrite, then Add Rule. Click Reverse Proxy - it will prompt you to install ARR and also update URL Rewrite if necessary. After it installs, just click cancel on creating the new rule. Your redirect should work now.

Comment: Thanks for the clever work around to get ARR installed.  Unfortunately, after the install the redirect still doesn't work.  While I wasn't prompted to restart anything, I did restart the xyz.com but it didn't fix it.  This is a production server so I'm limited to what I can do during the day but will reboot the entire server tonight and see if anything shakes loose.

Comment: At this point, all I can suggest is to use [Failed Request Tracing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to troubleshoot. It's ugly, but I've used it in the past to figure out rewrite issues.

Comment: I will look into Failed Request Tracing.  I appreciate all your suggestions.  This seems like such a simple task - it's frustrating that it is so elusive to implement.